# Drupal how to create a rule that executes a cgi script

Tags: drupal, cgi

I am working on a Drupal site and I am really not that familar  with the it but my task is to create a rule that will run a cgiscript that returns some data is this possible I know you can send emails but not sure how to run a script any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the core **PHP filter** module and on your rule Action add a **PHP > Execute custom PHP code**.